# Pandas: Cumulative return function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

I have a dataframe such as the following:

```
  Index      Return
2008-11-21   0.153419
2008-11-24   0.037421
2008-11-25   0.077500
```

What's the best way to calculate a cumulative return across all columns on the last row?

Following is the intended result:

```
  Index      Return
2008-11-21   0.153419
2008-11-24   0.037421
2008-11-25   0.077500
Cumulative   0.289316
```

Where cumulative return calculated as follows:

```
cumulative = (1 + return1) * (1 + return2) * (1 + return3) - 1
```

What is the best way to perform this in pandas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

there is a pandas `cumprod()` method for that. this will work for every columns.

```
df.ix["Cumulative"] = ((df+1).cumprod()-1).iloc[-1]
```

this would be about 2 time faster than other solutions on large dataset:

```
In[106]: %timeit df.ix["Cumulative"] = ((df+1).cumprod()-1).iloc[-1]
10 loops, best of 3: 18.4 ms per loop
In[107]: %timeit df.ix['Cummulative'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x+1).prod()-1)
10 loops, best of 3: 32.9 ms per loop
In[110]: %timeit df.append(df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda col: (col + 1).prod() - 1), ignore_index=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 37.1 ms per loop
In[113]: %timeit df.append(df.apply(lambda col: prod([(1+c) for c in col]) - 1), ignore_index=True)
1 loop, best of 3: 262 ms per loop
```

I would suggest to **never** use apply if you can find a built-in method since apply is looping over the dataframe which makes it slow. Bult-in method are highly efficient and normally there is no way you are going to get faster than them using apply.

Comment: that was brilliantly faster!! but i have one column that includes NaN. Any workaround to skip those and not return NaN?

Comment: `df.ix["Cumulative"] = ((df.fillna(0)+1).cumprod()-1).iloc[-1]`  would replace NaN with 0 return.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

```
df.ix["Cumulative"] = (df['Return']+1).prod() - 1
```

This will add 1 to the `df['Return']` column, multiply all the rows together, and then subtract one from the result.  This will result in a simple float value.  The result will then be placed at the index "Cumulative".  Since that index doesn't exist yet, [it will be appended to the end of the DataFrame](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement):

```
               Return
2008-11-21   0.153419
2008-11-25   0.077500
2008-11-24   0.037421
Cummulative  0.289316
```

If you want to apply this across multiple columns:

```
df.ix['Cummulative'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x+1).prod()-1)
```

This would output the following (I made a second column called "Return2" that is a copy of "Return"):

```
               Return   Return2
2008-11-21   0.153419  0.153419
2008-11-25   0.077500  0.077500
2008-11-24   0.037421  0.037421
Cummulative  0.289316  0.289316
```

Comment: Thx @Jalepeno112, but how to apply across all columns?

Comment: Updated my answer.  Missed that part of your question.  It's very similar to @Psidom's answer but I think this one is more readable.

Comment: No problem.  You should take a look at @StevenG's answer though.

Answer (score 2):

With `pandas`, you can use the `prod()` method:

```
df.append(df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda col: (col + 1).prod() - 1), ignore_index=True)

#        Index    Return
#0  2008-11-21  0.153419
#1  2008-11-24  0.037421
#2  2008-11-25  0.077500
#3         NaN  0.289316
```

Or as @Randy C commented, this can be further simplified to:

```
df.append((df.iloc[:,1:] + 1).prod() - 1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Nice one. For just doing the calculation, it can be simplified a little to `(df['Return']+1).prod() - 1`.

Comment: @RandyC Yeah, that is a more succinct way for this problem.

Comment: Thx @Psidom , i did df = the above, it works great, except that my date index disappeared, and the cum return under the first column returns a NaN, despite not including any NaNs and the cumulative is not equal to zero. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just use `reduce`, though others might be able to come up with faster vectorized methods:

```
In [10]: pd.read_clipboard()
Out[10]:
        Index    Return
0  2008-11-21  0.153419
1  2008-11-24  0.037421
2  2008-11-25  0.077500

In [11]: reduce(lambda x, y: (1+x)*(1+y)-1, _10['Return'])
Out[11]: 0.28931612705992227
```

Note that in Python 3, `reduce` is part of the `functools` library, though it's a builtin for Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine:

```
from numpy import prod
df.append(df.apply(lambda col: prod([(1+c) for c in col]) - 1), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Sure, first `import numpy as np` and then: `df.append(df.apply(lambda col: prod([(1+c) for c in col if not np.isnan(c)]) - 1), ignore_index=True)`. If you try it out then let me know if it's not working!